# How to create a code split typescript module with a constructor using the factory pattern

Tags: typescript, webpack, factory-pattern, code-splitting

I have a number of adapters all implemented from an interface like so

```
export interface IAdapter {
   doSomething(): void;
}
```

and the implemented classes look very similar and basic to what you'd expect

```
export default class AdapterA implements IAdapter {
   private _property: string;
   constructor(someProperty: string) {
       this._property = someProperty;
   }
}
```

I have a factory for the adapters and want to use it somewhat like this

```
export abstract class AdapterFactory {
    static async getInstance(name: string) Promise<IAdapter> {
        switch(name) {
            case 'a':
                return import('./adapters/adapter-a');
            case 'b':
                return import('./adapters/adapter-b');
        }
    }
}
```

After the code calling the factory I'd like to be able to use the returned module to instantiate a new instance of the adapter like

```
const adapterModule = await getInstance('a');
const myNewAdapter = new adapterModule('prop');
myNewAdapter.doSomething();
```

When I try this within the factory I get:

```
Type 'typeof import("/[absolute path]/adapters/AdapterA")' provides no match for the signature 'new (someProperty: string): IAdapter'
```

So I tried adding a definition of new (which I didn't like) like so:

```
export interface IAdapter {
   new(someProperty: string): IAdapter;
   doSomething(): void;
}
```

now I get:

```
This expression is not constructable.
```

any help anyone can give would be greatly received

Comment: Missing `await`? `const adapterModule = await getInstance('a');`

Comment: @AlekseyL. sorry about that, that's a typo in my question

Comment: Ah, yes, you probably need to extract from `default`(e.g: `const { default: adapterModule } = await getInstance('a')`)

Comment: @AlekseyL. please please please out that as an answer you've saved my day :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imported constructor [should be extracted](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) from `default`:

```
const { default: adapterModule } = await getInstance('a');
```

> The reason we need default is that since webpack 4, when importing a CommonJS module, the import will no longer resolve to the value of module.exports, it will instead create an artificial namespace object for the CommonJS module.

---

Not related small suggestions:

- rename `getInstance` -> `getConstructor`
- change return type to `Promise<IAdapterConstructor>`

where `IAdapterConstructor` is:

```
interface IAdapterConstructor {
  new(someProperty: string): IAdapter;
}
```